# MS Access Sort Access report by start of string

Tags: ms-access, report

Hi all I have a question, I have a report where I have some indicators about breakdown of machines. I have there a column where there is a time of the breakdown.

The problem is the company works on 2 shifts a day. Day shift and Night shift. The day shift starts at 7AM and end at 7PM and the night shift continues.

The problem is I want to start the sorting from the 7AM and go on... like this

> 7AM
>
> 8AM
>
> 9AM
>
> 10AM
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 23PM
>
> 24PM
>
> 1AM
>
> 2AM
>
> 3AM
>
> 4AM
>
> 5AM
>
> 6AM

Can someone halp me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Shift* the times to appear as starting at Midnight:

```
DateAdd("h", -7, [ShiftStartTime])
```

An expression like this, you can sort the report by.

If text time, convert to *Date*:

```
DateAdd("h", -7, CDate([ShiftStartTime]))
```

Comment: You should change that. Always handle date and time as Date, not text. If you can't, see edited answer, please.

Comment: Thank you very much Gustav!

Answer (score 1):

In your data source for the report, you could build a custom value for what shift something is on and then sort by that. For example

Shift: If(BreakdownTime>=23:00 or <=0700,"night","Day")

Then in your report you add the "Shift" field as a grouping.